# asp.net mvc controller with multiple lists and "return to list" link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, hyperlink

If you have 5 list views in a controller and in each list you can go to edit, details or delete.
On the edit, details and delete page youo have a link 'return to list'.
What's the best method to 'remember' to which list action you must return?

As a solution I've put some info like CurrentAction in the ViewModel and used that in the View. But if you want to use this with different controllers instead of one...
(You can use a Currentcontroller, CurrentArea, but that's not a 'beautifull' solution)

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult List2()
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult List3()
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult List4()
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Create(...)
        {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(...)
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(...)
        {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(...)
        {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(...)
        {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(...)
        {
        ...
    }
}
```

thanks

Filip

Comment: im totally confused. why do you have 5 list views? what do they do?

Comment: views with different columns of totally different filter fields (List2,3,4 is for simplicity, in my app I gave it proper names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Request.UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to examine from where did user come to delete ot edit screens.Then bind url to return to list command.

Answer (score 0):

You can set TempData["ReturnUrl"] in your caller action and then use it to set the url of return to list hyperlink.

Comment: it works when you put Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri directly in the view